# Sum numbers in lines grouped in blocks with headers (with Bash and AWK)

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sum

Assuming I have the following example output:

```
Node hostabc foofoofoo
        1 foo
        1 ...
        1 ...
        1 ...
        1 ...
        5 ...
Node hostcde ...
        1 ...
        10 ...
```

How can I get the sum of the numbers for each host (without using temporary files, and using Bash and AWK only)?

For example:

```
hostabc     10
hostcde     11
```

Comment: And mind putting what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following `awk` command:

```
awk '/^Node/{n=$2;next}{t[n]+=$1}END{for(n in t){print n,t[n]}}' file
```

Better explained as a multiline script:

```
# If the line starts with 'Node'
/^Node/ {
    # Set n(ame) to the value of the second field
    n=$2
    # No further actions on this line
    next
}
{
    # Add the value of the first field to t(otals)[n(name)]
    t[n]+=$1
}
# Once the end of input has been reached
END{
    # Iterate trough t(otals) keys
    for(n in t) {
        # Print the total along with the name
        print n,t[n]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$ awk '/^Node/{if(sum)print sum;printf "%s ", $2; sum=0;next} {sum+=$1} END{print sum}' file
hostabc 10
hostcde 11

/^Node/ {            # process Node starting lines
    if(sum)          # won't print sum (empty line) at the beginning
        print sum  
    printf "%s ", $2 # print the host name beforehand
    sum=0            # reset sum
    next             # no need to process further on Node records
}
{
    sum+=$1          # sum
} 
END {
    print sum        # print after the last line also
}
```

Comment: The advantage of this solution is that it guarantees the output to be in order. +1